# Unnecessary boxing inspection reported by IDE

Tags: java, ide

### Unnecessary boxing inspection reported by IDE

I was recently checking out some code that was posted on Oracle tutorials regarding Swing#JTable. There were a few warning messages that were returned by IntelIJ regarding the boxing of primitive variables inside the multidimensional array holding the Table data.

---

**Here is the array found which is taken from [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components/SimpleTableDemo.java):**

```
Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
                    "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
            {"John", "Doe",
                    "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sue", "Black",
                    "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Jane", "White",
                    "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Joe", "Brown",
                    "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };
```

---

**All the wrapped variables were receiving this message:**

> "Unnecessary boxing 'new Integer(5)' 
>   Reports "boxing", e.g. wrapping of primitive values in objects. Boxing is unnecessary under Java 5 and newer, and can be safely removed.
>   This inspection only reports if the project or module is configured to use a language level of 5.0 or higher."

---

I know the concept of boxing and unboxing in Java, my question would be as to why it's *'irrelevant'* in newer version of Java as I've seen many developers discuss it or use it recently.

Also, since boxing is not required what should 'new Integer(5)' be replaced with?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thanks to autoboxing in Java 5 and newer, you don't have to call the Integer and Boolean constructors to manually "box" the primitive values. The IDE seems to recommend you write the code as:

```
Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", 5, false},
            {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", 3, true},
            {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", 2, false},
            {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", 20, true},
            {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", 10, false}
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Joni, may I ask what benefit this has? Obviously disregarding the need to write less code

Comment: @Juxhin `Boolean` auto(un)boxing uses `Boolean.FALSE` and `Boolean.TRUE` instead of creating new `Boolean` instances, so your overhead is less. Similarly, `Integer` maintains a private cache of `Integer` objects representing `-128` to `+127`, and auto(un)boxing will use those if it can instead of creating new instances. Either let the compiler auto(un)box for you, or use the `.valueOf()` methods, which check the caches first.

Comment: @JonK Thanks alot for explaining that JonK!

Comment: In addition to saving you a little bit of memory, autoboxing gives certain guarantees about comparisons using reference semantics. For example, since an autoboxed boolean will be either Boolean.TRUE or Boolean.FALSE, not some other `Boolean` instance, you can compare them directly with the `==` operator. Otherwise you would have to use the `equals` method.